# AWS Lambda GoLang handler API

Tags: go, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

Is it possible to implement Lambda function handler with custom API?

For aws-lambda-go the valid handler is one of following types:

```
//  func ()
//  func () error
//  func (TIn) error
//  func () (TOut, error)
//  func (TIn) (TOut, error)
//  func (context.Context) error
//  func (context.Context, TIn) error
//  func (context.Context) (TOut, error)
//  func (context.Context, TIn) (TOut, error)
```

In my case, `TIn` is KinesisEvent containing `MySpecificType` as a payload.
I'm looking for the way (maybe to overwrite `lambda.Start()`) to be able to create the handler of type

```
func(MySpecificType) error
```

The goal is to avoid extracting the payload from KinesisEvent in every lambda and make the handler source independent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the solution is quite simple. Just overwrite the lambda.Start() method:

```
func Start(handler func(t * MySpecificType, i int) error) {

    lambda.Start(func(kinesisEvent events.KinesisEvent) (err error) {

        for i, record := range kinesisEvent.Records {

            mySpecType := new(MySpecificType)
            if err = json.Unmarshal(record.Kinesis.Data, mySpecType); err != nil {
                logrus.Errorf("records[%d]: %s", i, err)
                continue
            }

            err = handler(mySpecType, i)
        }
        return
    })
}
```

and then:

```
// main.go
func Handler(m *MySpecificType, index int) error {
// ...
}

func main() {
    <wherever_you_put_it_package>.Start(Handler)
    // instead of lambda.Start(Handler)
}
```